# Do we allow different political views?

Tags: discussion, scope

We all know that politics are opinions and a very subjective topic, but I think the site will be too dull if we add too many constraints. How do we solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean by "too dull", but I must point out that I visit the site to learn and not to be entertained.

Comment: sure,me too,just like it to be colorful not black and white

Answer (score 10):

Political Opinions are irrelevant.  I care about the facts you use to make your case.

In forensics (the Debate kind, not the CSI kind), it is typical to be assigned a proposition and a position.  Often the position may or may not be your own opinion.  That is irrelevant.  The question is - can you make the case? Can you marshal reason and facts to be persuasive to a uncommitted academic.  That's your audience here - not the ideologues.

Put another way, I don't care if you think Adolf Hitler deserves the Nobel Peace Prize.  What I care about is the political case you make. On the other hand, you might also believe that women and men should able to vote - but if you can't tell me why, I don't care.  (And, yes, for the record, I think voting is good, because it more directly ties the legitimacy of the government to the consent of the governed.)

If you can dispassionately describe the potential effects of a given policy (both for and against), you will always be "right" in an academic stance.  Whether or not someone agrees with you *should be* irrelevant.

The real case to be made here isn't what you think, but why.  If you can marshal arguments that consist of facts that be proven and lack leaps of logic, you should be able to find upvotes.